# Changing variable in one file conflicts the data for other file in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having weird problem in React JS. I have two classes named as  Notes.js and DataTables.js

I'm using DataTables in Note.js like this

```
 <DataTables
     keyField="id"
     columns={columns}
     url={this.state.url}
     useCallBack={true}
     onEdit={this.onEdit}
  />
```

**Please Note that DataTables.js is my own custom created DataTable.js not react-datatable.**

All the work like fetching data from URL and showing it in tabular form is in DataTables.js file.

**Note.js Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Constant } from "../shared/Constants";
import DataTables from "../shared/DataTables";
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import BreadCrumb from "../shared/BreadCrumb";
import "../Style.css";

const columns = Constant.notes;

export class Notes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      url: "notes/get_notes",
      showModal: false,
      note: [],
    };
    this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this);
    this.onAdd = this.onAdd.bind(this);
    this.onUpdate = this.onUpdate.bind(this);
    this.saveNote = this.saveNote.bind(this);
  }

  onUpdate(key, value) {
    let noteData = this.state.note;
    noteData[key] = value;
    this.setState({
      note: noteData,
    });
  }

  saveNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  onEdit(n) {
    this.setState({
      note: n,
      showModal: true,
    });
  }

  onAdd() {
    this.setState({
      note: [],
      showModal: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Modal
          show={this.state.showModal}
          aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg"
          onHide={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
        >
          <form method="post" onSubmit={this.saveNote}>
            <Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Title>My Note</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="text-muted">Note Title</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Note Title"
                      className="form-control"
                      ref="title"
                      value={this.state.note.title}
                      onChange={(e) => this.onUpdate("title", e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="text-muted">Content</label>
                    <textarea
                      onChange={(e) => this.onUpdate("content", e.target.value)}
                      className="form-control"
                      style={{ height: "250px" }}
                      placeholder="Content"
                    >
                      {this.state.note.content}
                    </textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button
                variant="secondary"
                onClick={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
              >
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
                Save Note
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </form>
        </Modal>

        <BreadCrumb
          title="My Notes"
          useCallBack={true}
          onAdd={this.onAdd}
          active_link="Notes"
          link=""
          link_text="Add New"
        />

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="card-title">Notes</div>

                <DataTables
                  keyField="id"
                  columns={columns}
                  url={this.state.url}
                  useCallBack={true}
                  onEdit={this.onEdit}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Notes;
```

I'm having Problem in Note.js on **onUpdate** function

```
  onUpdate(key, value) {
    let noteData = this.state.note;
    noteData[key] = value;
    this.setState({
      note: noteData,
    });
  }
```

**Problem:** When I update a field in Modal as you can see in my code, then my Table in DataTable.js automatically gets updated, I'don't why :/

Here is DataTables.js function where I'm sending data to onEdit function

```
const TableData = () => {
      return (
        <tbody>
          {tableData.length === 0 ?
          <tr>
            <td className="text-center" colSpan="5"><strong>No Data Found</strong></td>
          </tr>
          :
          tableData.map((tData) => (
            <tr key={tData[this.props.keyField]}>
              {this.props.columns.map((item, index) => (
                <td key={index} className="table-content">
                  {index === 0 ? 
                    [(useCallback === true ? <span key={"sub_"+index} className="link" onClick={() => this.props.onEdit(tData)}>{tData[item.dataField]}</span> : 
                      <Link
                      to={
                        this.props.edit_link +
                        "/" +
                        tData[this.props.edit_key_first] + (this.props.edit_key_second ? "/" +
                        tData[this.props.edit_key_second] : '')
                      }
                    >
                      {tData[item.dataField]}
                    </Link>
                    )]
                    : (
                    tData[item.dataField]
                  )}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      );
    };
```

Please check gif image below so you can understand it :P

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an onChange function that is updating the content

```js
onChange={(e) => this.onUpdate("content", e.target.value)}
```

If you don't want to change the content while typing then you will have to remove this.

Comment: I know but the problem is it is changing content of table with modal form, but it should change the data only in modal not table

Comment: They are different files one is Note.js and other is DataTables.js

Comment: If you only want to change in input and not the table, then you don't need this onChange function. What this does : when you type you call the onUpdate function which changes the state, resulting the change in table also. From your question , you don't want the table to update so you should not the update the state on change

Comment: Actually I know I have so many work around, but I want to know why this is happening because I'm using setState on my local variable which is in class Notes.js but it also changes the content of the table